# Fluent NHibernate HQL Assigning multiple class types to multiple table select query

Tags: nhibernate, select, hql, fluent

I know how to assign class type to the data retrieved from single table like this:

HQL query:

```
select s from Employee e join e.Store s where s.Id = 1
```

Code:

```
var stores = session.CreateQuery(hql).List<Store>();

foreach (var store in stores)
{
    Console.WriteLine(store.Name);

    foreach (var product in store.Products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    " + product.Name);
    }
}
```

But how can we assign multiple class types to multiple tables join query? Currently I'm unable to specify any class type as data is coming from multiple tables.

HQL query:

```
select distinct s.Name,p.Name,p.Price,p.Location.Aisle,p.Location.Shelf from Store s join s.Products p where s.Id = 1
```

Code:

```
var rows = session.CreateQuery(hql).List(); // Using List() instead of List<T>()

for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
    IList cols = (IList)rows[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < cols.Count; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(cols[j] + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a transformer. One option is to specify an EntityMap transformer.

```
session.CreateQuery.SetTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap)
```

This will return a list of dictionaries that will contain name value pairs based on your query. Alternatively, you can create a POCO object that maps to your query

```
public class MyProjection
{
   public string SName { get; set; }
   public string PName { get; set; }
   public float Price { get; set; }
   public string Aisle { get; set; }
   public string Shelf { get; set; }
}
```

Then specify a different transformer

```
session.CreateQuery.SetTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<MyProjection>())
      .List<MyProjection>();
```

Keep in mind you'll need to specify aliases for both approaches

```
select distinct s.Name as SName,p.Name as PName,p.Price as Price,
     p.Location.Aisle as Aisle, p.Location.Shelf as Shelf...
```